# Netlify running not excepted

Tags: reactjs, netlify

when i running my react app on localhost, it return to page, my url is: **http://localhost:3000/danh-muc/1/1-kiem-thu-phan-mem**

but when i run it on my netlify, it return page 404, my url on netlify is:
**https://flamboyant-montalcini-da8726.netlify.app/danh-muc/1/1-kiem-thu-phan-mem**

[image]

it is the first time i use netlify. In addition to, my custom page 404 was lost, How to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

i have a answer for this question, i add file "_redirects" in public folder with content:

```
/*    /index.html   200
```